# How to encode json passed from django by javascript in template

Tags: javascript, json, django

I path json object to template as context, and want to use this in template.

it look like this in source code of browser

```
 var json = "{&#x27;meta&#x27;: {&#x27;chord_style&#x27;: &#x27;bossa&#x27;
```

How can I encode this string as json object???

Comment: To convert that "json" into a valid JSON string try using `const data = json.replace(/&#x27;/gm, '"')`?

Comment: Then to convert the JSON into a JS Object (not a JSON object) use `JSON.parse(data)`

Comment: Thank you I just need to `replace &#x27`. solved!!

Comment: I've added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing the `&#x27;` with double-quotes.

```js
const enocodedjson = "{&#x27;meta&#x27;: {&#x27;chord_style&#x27;: &#x27;bossa&#x27;}}";
const json = enocodedjson.replace(/&#x27;/gm, '"');
const data = JSON.parse(json);

console.log(data);
```